# rename 'themes' folder prestashop version 1.6

Tags: prestashop

I searched the internet but I have not found anything to enlighten me.
 
I'm looking for ways to rename the 'themes' folder, can you help?
 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do next (not tested):

1. Rename it e.g. using FTP client
2. then in `config/defines_uri.inc.php` find lines:

   `define('_PS_THEME_DIR_',_PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/themes/'._THEME_NAME_.'/');
   define('_THEMES_DIR_', __PS_BASE_URI__.'themes/');
   ...
   define('_PS_THEME_MOBILE_DIR_',_PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/themes/'._PS_DEFAULT_THEME_NAME_.'/mobile/');
   define('_THEME_MOBILE_DIR_',__PS_BASE_URI__.'themes/'._PS_DEFAULT_THEME_NAME_.'/mobile/');`

and change `themes` on new name.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for that solution, and this what I did:

1. Rename folder name on FTP
2. Rename `directory` column of actual theme in `ps_theme` table